# How to get URL parameters in RPG-based CGI script?

Tags: apache, ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibmhttpserver

I am trying to find an API similar to [`QtmhGetEnv`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaie/rzaieapi_qtmhgetenv.html) that allows me to read URL parameters in an RPG-based CGI script.

Is there something like that available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternatives, but without knowing why QtmhGetEnv is not a good fit, these may not be desirable either:

QthmGetEnv is basically a wrapper for [getenv()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-getenv-search-environment-variables)

[ILEastic](https://github.com/sitemule) is one of the open solutions available on GitHub by Niels Liisberg and others

Brad Stone has had the [eRPG SDK](https://www.bvstools.com/) available for many years

Giovanni Perotti at Easy400 has had [CGIDEV2](https://www.easy400.net/cgidev2/start) available for many years

All of this 3rd party software has support from the developers and the midrange community.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the misunderstanding. I wasn't aware of `QthmGetEnv`'s relationship to `getenv` . I think I should be able to read the query string with `QthmGetEnv`. Thank you @Buck